# Single level URL from parent child Angular Router

Tags: angular, angular6, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

Using the following Angular 6 Routes in my jobs module and app module

My present working url is:  **www.mydomain.com/jobs/cook/94**

But I want to use single level URL for SEO purpose so i want the result like this: **www.mydomain.com/jobs-cook-94**

Job is my child module and i want to convert or redirect my all child level url to 1 level url separated by "**-**" insted of "**/**" , how to achive this in angular 6 lazy loading.

//app-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { 
   path: 'jobs',
   loadChildren: './jobs/jobs.module#JobsModule'
 },
 { 
   path: '**', redirectTo: '' 
 }
];
```

//jobs-routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component:JobsInHotelComponent,
  },
  { 
    path: ':category/:catID', 
    component: JobsInHotelComponent 
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use matcher property in your route definition to match routes and extract parameters from it.

For example

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    matcher: (url) => {
      if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^@[\w]+$/gm)) {
        return {
          consumed: url,
          posParams: {
            username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {})
          }
        };
      }
      return null;
    },
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
])
```

The example above checks to see that there is only one segment in the array, then uses regex to make sure the format of the username is a match. When it matches, it returns the entire URL consumed, and defines the username route parameter as a sub-string of the path. If there is no match, it returns null and the router continues to look for other routes that may match the URL. This works just as other routes do, allow you to define child routes, or even lazy loaded routes.

You can also refer [This awesome blog](https://medium.com/@brandontroberts/custom-route-matching-with-the-angular-router-fbdd48665483) for more information.